# How to check "The value of the local variable/field is not used" in Checkstyle?

Tags: checkstyle

How to check `The value of the local variable is not used` and `The value of the field is not used` using Checkstyle? In Eclipse there is a warning about that. But there's no in Checkstyle (i use `sun_checks.xml`, slightly modified).

I tried to write my own check, but being a newbie, only found how to calculate variable declarations (using `TokenTypes.VARIABLE_DEF`), but i am not sure how to find namely *usage* of these variables and fields...

Comment: Good news, checkstyle 9.3 has a rule called UnusedLocalVariable.

Answer (score 5):

Checkstyle can't do that, I'm afraid, but [PMD (rule)](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/rules/java/unusedcode.html) and [FindBugs (rule)](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#UUF_UNUSED_FIELD) can.

Checkstyle and PMD operate only on the Java source, and it is harder to deduce field and variable use only from the source. FindBugs operates on the compiled class files, so it has an easier job in this case. PMD can only detect unused private fields and variables, which can be found by looking at a single source file.

Writing an "unused private field/variable detector" for Checkstyle is possible, if tedious. I would recommend going with the PMD tool for this, which also features a light-weight Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Checkstyle 9.3 version has a check called UnusedLocalVariable https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#UnusedLocalVariable

Answer (score 2):

[Checkstyle 9.3](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/releasenotes.html#Release_9.3) introduced the [`UnusedLocalVariable` check](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#UnusedLocalVariable) which reports unused local variables. It does *not* detect unused fields.

To enable this check:

```
<module name="UnusedLocalVariable"/>
```

As of Checkstyle 10.1, this check still has some limitations: it doesn't report unused method arguments nor unused pattern variables. But at least it covers the most common cases with local variables.

References:

- [Checkstyle 9.3 Release Notes](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/releasenotes.html#Release_9.3)
- [UnusedLocalVariable module documentation](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_coding.html#UnusedLocalVariable)
- [Github issue](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/7504)