# Linter for unused parameters in a Java project?

Tags: java, styling, linter

CheckStyle had this option in the early versions:
http://api.dpml.net/checkstyle/3.5/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/usage/UnusedParameterCheck.html

Looking for a similar checker. Can anyone recommend me something?

Testing for this use case:

```
... main method .. 

        test("hello");
        return Longs.tryParse(request.getCategoryId());
    }

    @Nullable
    Long test(String unused) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        return null;
    }
```

I want the build to fail

Current CheckStyle version in use is 3.7. Not looking to downgrade.

Comment: Isn't the compilation going to fail when you try and run your automated tests (unit, integration, ...)?

Comment: That doesn't even compile. Why do you need a linter for that?

Comment: Sorry, I added a more clear example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check "The value of the local variable/field is not used" in Checkstyle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116032/how-to-check-the-value-of-the-local-variable-field-is-not-used-in-checkstyle)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not catch unused params. I just tried it out

Answer (score 0):

**Sonar Lint** supports this as rule "java:S1172":

> Unused method parameters should be removed - Unused parameters are
> misleading. Whatever the values passed to such parameters, the
> behavior will be the same.

[image: Sonar lint rule]

But there are some exceptions to this rule.

> The rule will not raise issues for unused parameters:
>
> - that are annotated with @javax.enterprise.event.Observes
> - in overrides and implementation methods
> - in interface default methods
> - in non-private methods that only throw or that have empty bodies
> - in annotated methods, unless the annotation is @SuppressWarning("unchecked") or @SuppressWarning("rawtypes"), inwhich
>   case the annotation will be ignored
> - in overridable methods (non-final, or not member of a final class, non-static, non-private), if the parameter is documented with a
>   properjavadoc.

Also **Eclipse IDE** supports this out of the box. This can be enabled in Java>Compiler>Errors/Warnings with option "Value of method parameter is not used"
[image: Eclipse compiler settings for unused method parameters]
This produces info/warning/error (as you configure) "The value of the parameter XXX is not used"

[image: Warning produced by Eclipse]